# How would I use pglogical from a downstream database?

Tags: pglogical

I'd like to use pglogical to replicate a set of tables, but I want to make all of my changes downstream from the master - to avoid risk, I don't want to make any modifications to the master database. I'd also like to start using pglogical now so we get familiar with the technology and can include it across all of our databases on our next release.

I don't need constant updates, so I came up with a plan, a cron job that:

1. Turns off streaming replication to a standby
2. Makes this standby a logically-replicating master (just for logical replication, no writes)

   - Stop postgresql
   - Copy off data dir
   - Make config changes
   - Start postgresql
   - Create pglogical extension
3. Catches up logical replication
4. Makes this database a streaming standby without logical replication again

   - Stop postgresql
   - Replace data dir with previous copy
   - Config changes
   - Start postgresql

My question - does this approach even make sense? Is there some easy way to accomplish this that I'm totally missing?